# Pig not able to read input file stored in HDFS

Tags: shell, hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

My input files are stored in the following directory format in hdfs

```
/data/drain*/*
/data/freight*/*
```

There are almost 10 json files in each folder.

Have written a pig script to read the input file. But the script reads the files only from /data/drain*/* and not from freight directory.

It shows the following logs after pig script execution

```
Successfully read 39 records from /data/drain*/*
Successfully read 0 records from /data/freight*/*
```

Load statement in pig script:

```
DrainData = load '/data/drain*/*' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader();
FreightData = load '/data/freight*/*' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader();
```

This is the directory structure in Hdfs

```
/data/drain/
/data/freight/
```

The Json file exists inside this directory(Sample file)

```
/data/drain/50499.json
/data/freight/61501.json
```

I am not able to figure out as to why it's not able to read from freight directory.

Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS : Hadoop version - 2.4.0, Apache Pig version - 0.12.0

Comment: could you show your load statement(s) as well as the directory structure of the two directories?

Comment: Fred, have updated my question.

Comment: Hi Aman... U have mentioned /data/drain/ as your directory. Then why u have mentioned /data/drain*/* in load statement of pig

Comment: the exact strucutre is /data/drain2756.finished/2756.json.